# How to restore blender's default view?

Tags: 3d-view, customization

Blender split the 3d view into 4 parts,I don't want this,I want the default blender 3d view,How do I go back?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @ShadyPuck Last time i checked when pressing CTRL ALT Q, you can't close them windows it creates, instead you have to do the key shortcut again.

Answer (score 3):

This called the Quad View.
You can go back to default *View* by Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>